# concatenate the data which came from model

Tags: php

I want to show the content of a table but instead of `sec_id` I want to show the `sec_name` by passing the `sec_id` in other function and get the `sec_name` and show it on the view. But I can not concatenate the variable `sec_name` because the last `sec_name` is show instead of all other `sec_name`.

This is the model

```
function get_subsec(){
$q=$this->db->query("SELECT subsec_id,subsec_name,order,role_id,sec_id FROM subsection");
return $q->result_array();
}

function show_secname($id){
$q=$this->db->query("SELECT name FROM section WHERE sec_id=".$id);
return $q->result_array();
}
```

This is the controller.

```
function get_subsec(){
$data["x"]=$this->amodel->get_subsec();
foreach($data["x"] as $s){
$y["k"]=$this->amodel->show_secname($s["sec_id"]);
}
$this->load->view("get_subsec",array_merge($data,$y));
}
```

This is the view

```
<?php foreach($x as $row){ 
echo $row["subsec_id"];
echo $row["subsec_name"];
echo $row["order"];
}?>
<?php foreach($k as $i){
echo $i["name"];
}?>
```

Comment: You should take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1505348